# How can filtering be possible without for loop using LINQ?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, collections, filtering

[image: Non Filtered data]

I have the requirement to filter this data on the basis of the following constraints.

- If multiple records exist for single consignmentId house keep that record against AddressTypeId == 5 and discard against AddressTypeId == 2
- If AddressTypeId == 5 do not exist against specific Consignment Id ( means only one record ) Just housekeep that one.

At the moment I have the following Code :

```
List<ConsignmmentRecord> finalConsignments = new List<ConsignmmentRecord>();

var allConsignmentData = ConsignmentToAddresses.Where(Pr => Pr.AddressTypeId == 2 || Pr.AddressTypeId == 5).ToList();

foreach(ConsignmmentRecord record in allConsignmentData )
{             
   ConsignmmentRecord Consignment = finalConsignments.Find(Pr => (Pr.ConsignmentId == record.ConsignmentId));

   if ( Consignment ==  null )                  
        finalConsignments.Add(record);                    
   else
   {                                                
        if (Consignment.AddressTypeId == 2)
        {
           finalConsignments.RemoveAll(Pr => Pr.ConsignmentId == Consignment.ConsignmentId);
           finalConsignments.Add(record);
        }                   
   }                                    
 }
```

I would like to remove the above loop and replace it with a LINQ statements, if possible

I am attaching my desired result as a screenshot

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your method as follows:

```
var finalConsignments = ConsignmentToAddresses
    // You group by ConsignmentId, as you want a single record for group
    .GroupBy(c => c.ConsignmentId)
    // Then you check if there is in the group a record with AddressTypeId == 5 ...
    .Select(g => g.Where(x => x.AddressTypeId == 5).Any()
        // ... if it exists you take it ...
        ? g.Where(x => x.AddressTypeId == 5).First()
        // ... otherwise you take the record with AddressTypeId == 2
        : g.Where(x => x.AddressTypeId == 2).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @user449689 :
This really worked as per my expectation... :-)